# Cannot rotate or scale imported .obj from Sketchup

Tags: objects

[image]Have tried to import this .obj into Blender. Cannot rotate or scale the object itself like other objects I have imported.

Comment: Attach the file so someone can look into it. Am guessing you have the object locked down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have accidentally lock your transformation here? If not upload the file so we can look into it? Another reason why models can't move is that it's a child of a parent object. If the vehicle comes with a rigged system ... I believe it could be the problem. You can try to break the parent-child link by Hitting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select "Clear Parent"

[image]

Clear Parent Menu
[image]

Comment: ...also, transform parameters had been locked.